# UIAlertView On Button Click

Tags: objective-c

Yes, I've already Googled this question and I've used the exact code, but that's still not working.

Here is my current Objective-C code:

```
- (IBAction)btnTemp:(id)sender
{
    if (_deepSwitch.on == TRUE)
    {
        [self TempCleaner];
        _progress.progress += 1;
    }
    UIAlertView *cleaned = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done!" message:@"Your device is now clean. Restarting SpringBoard." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [cleaned show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {
        NSLog(@"clicked");
    }
}
```

Why isn't this working? I've tried buttonIndex 0, and cancel button!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the alert view's delegate to `self`

```
UIAlertView *cleaned = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done!" message:@"Your device is now clean. Restarting SpringBoard." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

Also, make sure that the class from which you are presenting the alert view declares the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol

```
//YourClass.h
@interface YourClass : SuperClass <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Comment: @user3818701 No problem, it's a common mistake that I make sometimes.

Comment: @user3818701 welcome to SO, If someone answered your question and if that answer really worked for you, there is no obligation but should accept that answer by clicking green bordered checkmark under the up/down buttons. Every accepted answers gives +2 rep to you. I am writing this because as I can see you have some questions and you got your answers but you did not accept any of them. I am just giving information, feel free to accept answers or not. thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know I could do that. I just upped this :)